# Python: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer?

Tags: python, numpy

I am getting an error `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`in this part of my code. Can someone tell me why am I getting the error and how to fix it?

```
for y in range(-x/2, x/2):
    #Some function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `-x/2` with `-int(x/2)` and `x/2` with `int(x/2)`. Division in Python returns a `float` and `range` only takes `ints`.